# Optimizing SQL for large volumes

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, automationstudio

We're working with somewhat large sets of data, around 15M - 35M records per DE, each row with 150+ attributes.

What are some ways to optimize SQL queries when handling many records?

- For an exaple, using intermediate DE's and SQL queries selecting TOP 50% from a DE with 14M records will still take approximately 21-27 minutes to run, meaning with any major data increase these queries will time out.
- Data flow is Synchonized DE -> Shared DE -> sub-BU DE per object.

Salesforce's [**own documentation**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000317499&type=1&mode=1) on optimizing Queries is really basic and not of use this time around.

Here is as example Query

```
SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT
// attribute list //
FROM Synchronized DE
WHERE
// conditions // 
ORDER BY 
// condition //
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My preferred method is to leverage the hidden, pseudo-identity `_customObjectKey` column to break up queries into manageable chunks.  As long as your scheme can accommodate the overwrite-update/append-update/append-x pattern:

Here's a 4-group example using the mod operator:

- Query 1: `where de._customobjectKey % 4 = 0 /* action:overwrite */`
- Query 2: `where de._customobjectKey % 4 = 1 /* action:append/update */`
- Query 3: `where de._customobjectKey % 4 = 2 /* action:append/update */`
- Query 4: `where de._customobjectKey % 4 = 3 /* action:append/update */`

The first query would be an overwrite, then subsequent ones would be updates.

Also, if there's a date parameter that limits the scope of rows you should be considering, make a staging DE that includes only the most recently updated records, then base the subsequent queries on that staging DE.

Comment: Hey Adam, I'm trying to make sense of this.  _CustomObjectKey is  just a hidden unique identifier for a record in a DE, right?  Can you help me understand the purpose of the MOD operator and how the _CustomObjectKey's value correlates with an overwrite/append/update?

Comment: The modulo (`%`) operator returns the remainder of a division operation.  The hidden `_customObjectKey` is just a semi-sequental number, so if you divide it by 4 (in this case) the remainder will always be between 0 and 3 for every potential value of `_customObjectKey`.  If you employ this you have to first overwrite with the first query and then append or update with subsequent ones since all of the queries together should target a single DE.  You don't want to do an for overwrite every group.

Comment: Ah yesss that makes sense.  Thank you sir!!